# How to define generic extension method that returns type of sub generic

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I have a definition like this:

```
 public static IQueryable<D> ReturnDTO<E, D>(this IQueryable<E> query)
        where D : BaseDTO, new()
        where E : BaseObjectWithDTO<D, int>
{
    //expression tree code to convert
}
```

BaseObjectWithDTO defines what type it's DTOs are. Hence I would have thought the by defining E I would have been also defining D.

But IQueryable.ReturnDTO() requires that the generic parameters be specified like this:

```
 IQueryable.ReturnDTO<someEntity, someDTO>();
```

Which is obviously UGLY.

I tried making this `IQueryable<E>` as this `IQueryable<BaseObjectWithDTO<D, int>>` instead but then this has nothing as the in of the func because it won't take a type inferred by the Generic Parameter of the `IQuerayble`:

```
var projection = Expression.Lambda<Func<E, D>>(memberInitExpression, itemParam);
```

Ideas on how to get this to not require the types be passed every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible as you currently have it designed, this MSDN [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states that type inference is not possible in this scenario:

> The same rules for type inference apply to static methods and instance
>   methods. The compiler can infer the type parameters based on the
>   method arguments you pass in; it cannot infer the type parameters only
>   from a constraint or return value.

That means you have to pass in a parameter of your type to this method for the compiler to be able to infer the types.

Comment: This isn't a method with no parameters, even though the syntactic sugar of extension methods might suggest that.

Comment: But D and E are only referenced as type constraints and return value, so I believe this still applies. Your own answer justifies that (you pass in an object of type `D` and type inference works).

Comment: I was mainly focused on the last quoted sentence, "Therefore type inference does not work with methods that have no parameters." Since there is a parameter here, that particular part is irrelevant. It's the part about being unable to infer from a constraint that's most relevant here, because that's where you were hoping it would infer `D` from.

Comment: Understood, I just copied the whole paragraph, but I see your point.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, C#'s generic type inference system isn't as powerful as it could be. If you include a parameter involving `D`, then it can infer it. For example...

```
public static IQueryable<D> ReturnDTO<E, D>(this IQueryable<E> query,
                                 IQueryable<BaseObjectWithDTO<D, int>> dummy)

// now you can do...
myQueryable.ReturnDTO(myQueryable);
// instead of 
myQueryable.ReturnDTO<BaseObjectWithDTO<BaseDTO, int>, BaseDTO>();
```

It's confusing and arguably a poor design to pass the same variable in twice, but it's better (IMHO) than having to explicitly specify the types or resort to reflection or other runtime techniques to extract the types (when that's otherwise unnecessary).

Since you aren't actually going to use the `dummy` parameter, it doesn't matter what the value is, as long as the type is right, so you might still be able to use this at the end of a query chain, e.g. this will still return the expected value, even though you pass in two different `IQueryable`s.

```
var result = otherQueryable.Where(...).ReturnDTO(otherQueryable);
```

If you prefer to be slightly less cryptic, you could make the dummy parameter `D dummy`, and then e.g. `myQueryable.ReturnDTO(default(SomeDTO))` (here using [`default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xwth0h0d.aspx) as a clear way of getting a null or default value without having a reference to a variable/field/property of that type) if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the type, but it doesn't have to be done explicitly in the `q.Return<E,D>()`.  There are ways that you can pass specify the type parameter so that it can be inferred implicitly.  To do that, you'll need to change the signature a bit.

```
 public static IQueryable<D> ReturnDTO<E, D>(this IQueryable<E> query, D dtoTypeExample = default(D))
    where D : BaseDTO, new()
    where E : BaseObjectWithDTO<D, int>
 {
    //expression tree code to convert
 }
```

Now, even though there's a default parameter, the compiler won't be able to get it unless you pass some argument in.  The thing you pass in doesn't have to be used by the method in any other way though.  For example, assume you have:

```
public class ProductDTO : BaseDTO { 
   public static ProductDTO Empty { get { return new ProductDTO(); } }
}

public class Product : BaseObjectWithDTO<ProductDTO,int> { 
   public static IQueryable<Product> QuerySource { get; set; }
}
```

You could then call:

```
ProductDTO dto = Product.QuerySource.ReturnDTO(ProductDTO.Empty);
```

I'm not saying that this is necessarily a good idea, but you could do it.  Also, it doesn't have to be the actual type that you pass in - you just need to pass in something that's close enough for the compiler to infer the intended type.  For example, you could have a signature like:

```
 public static IQueryable<D> ReturnDTO<E, D>(this IQueryable<E> query, Func<D,D> dtoIdentity = default(Func<D,D>))
    where D : BaseDTO, new()
    where E : BaseObjectWithDTO<D, int>
 {
    //expression tree code to convert
 }
```

then if you have:

```
public class ProductDTO : BaseDTO { 
   public static ProductDTO Identity(ProductDTO dto){ return dto; };
}

public class Product : BaseObjectWithDTO<ProductDTO,int> { 
   public static IQueryable<Product> QuerySource { get; set; }
}
```

You could then call:

```
ProductDTO dto = Product.QuerySource.ReturnDTO(ProductDTO.Identity);
```

This might make more semantic sense to some, but it's somewhat subjective.  Once again, I'm not recommending this, just saying that you can do it.  If you do decide to do it though, it might save you a little work to have a self-referential generic base (**Warning:** [Eric Lippert discourages this kind of thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx)).  But anyway, your design would then look like:

```
public abstract class BaseDTO<T> where T : BaseDTO<T>, new()
{ 
    public static T Empty { get { return new T(); } }
}

public class ProductDTO : BaseDTO<ProductDTO> { }
```

You could also add the type constraint to your `ReturnDTO` method if you want to enforce an invariant that all DTOs were then self-referential derivatives of `BaseDTO<T>` with public parameterless constructors.  But, if you're trying to write what would conventionally be considered good code you probably won't do any of this and you'll just close your eyes and explicitly use the parameter constraint if you think it's ugly.

There is one other thing I thought of, which wouldn't be so frowned upon.  Think about the `Queryable.Cast<T>` and `Queryable.OfType<T>` methods.  They take a non generic `IQueryable` parameter but returns an `IQueryable<T>`.  If you make sure to validate your assumptions about the parameter, it's probably clean enough.  Then you would lose some compile-time type-safety though.  You would need to have a non-generic base like `BaseObjectWithDTO` that `BaseObjectWithDTO<TData,TKey>` would inherit from.  Your method would then look like:

```
 public static IQueryable<D> ReturnDTO<D>(this IQueryable<BaseObjectWithDTO> query)
    where D : BaseDTO, new()
 {
    if(query == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("query");
 if( !typeof(BaseObjectWithDTO<D,int>) .IsAssignableFrom(query.GetType().GetGenericParameters()[0])) 
          throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("query");

    //expression tree code to convert
 }
```

That's not terrible.  But it might not be good either.  It's probably better than the other options I listed, but who knows.

Another syntax that might work for you just occurred to me, but it's also pretty abusive.  Imagine you did go the `BaseDTO<T> where T : BaseDTO<T>,new()` route.  You could declare the method on that type to extract the DTO queryable.  This is what I'm thinking:

```
public abstract class BaseDTO<T> 
    where T : BaseDTO<T>, new()
{ 
   public static T From(BaseObjectWithDTO<T,int> entity){
      if(entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
      //expression tree code to convert 
   } 
}
```

then you don't really need that method `ReturnDTO` as an extension method anymore, because you have normal LINQ.  You could still add it as syntactic sugar if you want, but using these semantics instead, your call ends up looking like:

```
IQueryable<ProductDTO> dtoQuery = from entity in Product.QuerySource select ProductDTO.From(entity);
```

which can also be written as

```
Product.QuerySource.Select(entity => ProductDTO.From(entity));
```

and if you were using an `IEnumerable` instead of an `IQueryable` could be

```
Product.QuerySource.Select(ProductDTO.From);
```

**Please remember: All I'm saying is that you can do things this way.  I'm not saying you should.**